# Change folder of "next export"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've got following next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  dir: "src",
  outDir: "./build"
};
```

When I run `next build; next export;` my static files end up in newly created `out` folder.

I thought `outDir` overwrites that, but apparently not. So is there a way to tell next to output static files into `build` folder as opposed to `out`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#usage):

> Absolute path to the out/ directory (configurable with -o or --outdir

You can run:

```
next export -o build/
```

to redirect the build to `build` directory.

Comment: Updated link to the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#customizing-the-output-directory